# Decrypt Data using custom model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption

Currently I'm having a class name Student:

```
class Student {

public int StudentID {get;set;}

public string Details {get;set;}

public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

My html page:

```
<form action="" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="StudentID" value="Some Student ID" />
<input type="text" name="Details" value="" />
<input type="text" name="Address" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Current I'm using **StudentID** posted from Html form to Store **Address** and **Details** in Database which can be **changed by users in Client Side**.So to prevent this I'm thinking of Encrypting StudentID and store it in another property say StudentID_Encrypt with custom model binder attribute and post this encrypted data from html form to my Action method.
And my custom binder will decrypt this StudentID_Encrypt and store its value in original StudentID which I'll receive in my action method model.
Making my Student class like this :

```
class Student{

public int StudentID {get;set;}

[SomeCustomAttribute]
public string StudentID_Encrypt {get;set;}

public string Details {get;set;}

public string Address {get;set;}

}
```

Is this a proper way or is there any other way.Please Suggest.
Thank you in Advance !!

Comment: not allow the user to edit studenid is it correct? why don't you disable the input

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?  If a person sees the studentID, what are the downsides?  if you encrypt it you still need to send it back to the server to know which record to update.  if a person copies the encrypted data and posts it? how do you know?  This sounds like trying to get around having actual security around what a user can do.

Comment: @Fran I'm trying to stop user from editing other user data. Say If a particular user is allowed to edit data of StudentID 1,2,3 and if the user changes the studentID to say 6 in the hidden field then he will be able to change data which he is not suppose to change.This is what I'm trying to stop.By Encrypting StudentID to some long Encrypted String even if the user edit this string this string will not decrypt in Server side preventing the above scenario which I mentioned.

Comment: @BalajiMarimuthu its a hidden input and say what if user changes this hidden field value by using browser console.

Comment: How do you know that a person can't edit a certain record?

Comment: @VigneshPandi set readonly to HTML input element or property attribute in c#. I think that's the best way

Comment: @Fran I do have db record of which IDs a person/user can edit.

Comment: then you need to check that when a person tries to post data.  if that check fails you should probably send back a http 403 back that says the operation is forbidden.

Comment: @Fran I understand my problem can be solved by checking whether the user is allowed to edit a certain data or not before performing db operations. Consider 15 other table has relation with student table and user is changing ID of any of this table record and posting data from HTML form.In this scenario I have to check the same for all these 15 tables as well.

Comment: @Fran Did you get my problem ?

Comment: you're last comment doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Fran Say Student table has relation with Score table (one to many ) and I'm displaying both these table data to edit in HTML form. In this case if the user edit the scoreID value from browser hidden fields which is not related to the StudentID (who is not assigned to him) He will end up editing some other student data .To stop this, I have to first check for student ID validation and then have to get and validate all ScoreID related to that particular student  before doing any db change. This is just two tables but I'm talking about multiple related table .Thanks for your help

Comment: sounds like you need to look at your domain model.  it would be easy enough to only allow editing of the scores through the student record, like _student.AddScore.  then you only need to check that student id and verify it they match before allowing any edits on a student.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I think this is the solution. Please put your comment as answer,I will accept it.

Comment: Encrypting the value will do nothing at all to solve the issue described in your first comment. You always validate the data in the POST method. You have the ID of the current user assuming they logged in, and you need to check if that user has the permission to edit that object, and if not, redirect them to an error page.